# Some doubts about the logic of JDBC in Spring Framework

Tags: java, database, spring, spring-mvc, jdbc

I am studying JDBC use on Spring Framework following this tutorial: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_jdbc_example.htm

So I have the following table named Student on my MySql DB:

```
mysql> describe Student;
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| ID    | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| NAME  | varchar(20) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| AGE   | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see in the tutorial link I have an interface named **StudentDAO** that describe the CRUD operation on this Student table of my DAO object

Ok, looking at the **StudentJDBCTemplate** class: this is an implementation of the **StudentDAO** interface, so in this class I have all the implementation for the CRUD method declared inside the interface.

Ok...I have some doubt about the JDBC method mean in this class.

For example when I have something like:

```
public void create(String name, Integer age) {
    String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";

    jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age);
    System.out.println("Created Record Name = " + name + " Age = " + age);
    return;
}
```

Ok...I think that this method **create a new record** in my Student table.

The SQL variable contains a String that rappresents my **query** and here I have the first doubt

When I have:

**String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";**

what exactly mean? It means that the two input parameter of my create() take the place of the "name" and "age" int this String?

mmm...this sound strange for me, because this look like a String (infact is whithin "")

The scond doubt is related to the following line:

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age);
```

If I have the SQL query inside the SQL String, why have I to pass also the variable name and age?

Can you help me to understand well how JDBC work?

Tnx

Andrea

Comment: read about [Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I have:
>
> **String SQL = "insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)";**
>
> what exactly mean? It means that the two input parameter of my create() take the place of the "name" and "age" int this String?

JDBC will replace the two `?` placeholders with the appropriate values. This is seen as a good practice as it helps prevent SQL injection.

Comment: Actually, the JDBC driver or even the database server will replace the `?` placeholders with the parameter value.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
insert into Student (name, age) values (?, ?)
```

means that you're inserting a record (row) into the table `Student`, specifying (in order) the name and age. Each '?' refers to the column name specified in order, so the first '?' is a placeholder for the name value etc. Note that you can insert a record and (constraints allowing) only specify a subset of the columns, so you could just specify the name *or* age, or something else if that column exists.

This placeholder (?) mechanism exists such that you don't have to worry about escaping your values for `name` etc., and producing by concatenation/replacement a SQL statement [that isn't valid](http://xkcd.com/327/). The placeholder allows you to insert any string for name without worrying about quotes, SQL comments etc., which would cause problems if you simply constructed your string using concatenation e.g.

```
String sql = "insert into Student... " + name + ", " + age;
```

Note that name and age in

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, name, age);
```

refer to the Java variables and not the table column names. They could just as easily be

```
jdbcTemplateObject.update(SQL, x, y);
```

Under the covers SPring will be using [PreparedStatements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) and it's instructive to read about these.

Comment: Please, can you explain me better what you mean as placeholder  mechanism? In this case what exactly mean the values(?, ?)

It means that if I would put only the name value in my table I have to do somethng like:
insert into Student (name) values (?) 

Is it right? If yes...what I have to do if I would put only the age value inside the new table row?

Tnx

Comment: That's pretty much it. If you wrote the SQL and forget the JDBC you'd write "insert into Student (name, age) values ('Andrea', 21)"